# reverse function keeps giving me errors

Tags: c, stack, swap

This is a function that calls to arrays in a stack of chararrays and integers. It is supposed to reverse the values, but first i have to figure out which is a string and which is an integer before i can switch them. but i keep getting errors. Does anything look ridiculosuly off on this?

```
void reverse(Stack *S)
// NOTE:  Called w/ user input 'r'   
// PRE:   Stack S is initialized  
// POST:  The first two values of the stack are reversed on the stack 
{
    int valone;
    int valtwo;
    char stringone[50];
    char stringtwo[50];

    if (S->size < 1)
    {
        printf("Error: There are less than 2 values on the stack \n");
    }  
    else
    { 
        valone = (float)topInt(S);
        strcpy(stringone, topString(S));
        pop(S);
        valtwo = (float)topInt(S);
        strcpy(stringone, topString(S));
        pop(S);

        if(stringone[0] == '\n')
        {
            pushInt(S, valone);
        }
        else if(valone == '\n')
        {
            pushString(S, stringone);
        }
        else if(stringtwo[0] == '\n')
        {
            pushInt(S, valtwo);
        }
        else if(valtwo == '\n')
        {
            pushString(S, stringtwo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: where is the definition of type Stack? Why you use a cast to float to store that value in a int? why sometimes you push strings, sometimes ints? your code is confusing...

Answer (score 1):

You are popping two values off the stack, but only pushing one value back onto it. You need to change one of the `else if`s to `if`.

```
    if(stringone[0] == '\n')
    {
        pushInt(S, valone);
    }
    else if(valone == '\n')
    {
        pushString(S, stringone);
    }

    if(stringtwo[0] == '\n')
    {
        pushInt(S, valtwo);
    }
    else if(valtwo == '\n')
    {
        pushString(S, stringtwo);
    }
```

I don't know if this will solve your problem. What **error** are you getting? Please post that.

Also, why are you using `\n` as some special value here? You will run into strange issues if `valone` or `valtwo` end up equivalent to the integral value of `\n`.

If I were you, I would change the approach to something like...

```
void reverse(Stack **S)
{
    Stack* newS = allocateEmptyStack();

    while (!isEmpty(*S))
    {
        StackItem* item = top(*S);
        pop(*S);
        push(newS, item);
    }

    freeStack(*S);
    *S = newS;

 }
```

Some potential definitions...

```
typedef enum ItemType
{
    STACK_STRING,
    STACK_INT,
    STACK_FLOAT
} ItemType;

typedef struct StackItem
{
    ItemType type;
    void* data;
    StackItem* next;
} StackItem;

typedef struct Stack
{
    StackItem* top;
} Stack;

Stack* allocateEmptyStack()
{
    Stack* S = malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    S->top = NULL;

    return S;
}

int isEmpty(Stack* S)
{
    if (S->top == NULL)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void freeStack(Stack* S)
{
    while (!isEmpty(S))
    {
        StackItem* item = top(S);
        pop(S);
        freeStackItem(item);
    }

    free(S);
}

StackItem* top(Stack* S)
{
    return S->top;
}

void pop(Stack* S)
{
    StackItem* topItem = top(S);

    if (topItem != NULL)
    {
        s->top = topItem->next;
    }
}

void push(Stack* S, StackItem* item)
{
    item->next = top(S);

     s->top = item;
}

StackItem* allocateStackItem(ItemType type, int dataSize)
{
    StackItem* item = malloc(sizeof(StackItem));

    item->data = malloc(dataSize);
    item->type = type;
    item->next = NULL;

    return item;
} 

void freeStackItem(StackItem* item)
{
    if (item->data != NULL)
        free(item->data);

    free(item);
}
```

An example of initializing a `Stack`...

```
Stack* S = allocateEmptyStack();

StackItem* item = allocateStackItem(STACK_INT, sizeof(int));
int* int_ptr = (int*)(item->data);
*int_ptr = 1234;

push(S, item);

const char* str = "this is a string";

item = allocateStackItem(STACK_STRING, strlen(str) + 1);
char* char_ptr = (char*)(item->data);
strcpy(char_ptr, str);

push(S, item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to be too harsh, but this code is tantamount to completely incoherent.
I can't imagine what valone = (float)topInt(S); is intended to do, since
valone is an int.  You also seem to be assigning both an integer identity
and a string identity to the top element of the stack.  You pop two items
off the stack and push at most one.  You strcpy to a fixed lenngth buffer
without checking the size of the string you are copying, and finally, if
you do push a string on the stack, you're pushing the local variable address
which will be invalid when the function exits.

Comment: I didn't actually notice anything right.  The test for too few items on the stack seems to be incorrect too. Oh dear...

Comment: Agreed. The code doesn't make much sense as-is. That's why I ended up coding up an example stack interface. That and it is a slow day at work...

Comment: The OP is clearly a newb, so coding for him won't teach him to fish.  I stick to pointing out problems and solutions in informal language, so they'll have the educational benefit of learning to think about and write code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand without more detail,but it looks like you are doing two pops and only one push.  You at least need to tale out your 2nd else.